# why the given code doesn't changes the values in the list?

Tags: python, list

```
e=map(int,raw_input().split())


e=sorted(e)
for i in e:

    p=e.count(i)
    i=i + p + 1
```

'''where's the mistake? as if I take a list [3,1] , it is just printing the list as [1,3] without adding.'''

Comment: You're not assigning to to list, or any of it elements, in the loop; you're only re-assigning your loop variable `i`, which is just a local name for the same object that's in the list. If I said "my best friend is Himanshu Jotwani", and then I said "my best friend is now the guy next to Himanshu Jotwani instead", that wouldn't turn you into the guy next to you. But that's all `i =` inside your loop does.

Comment: Also, if you _did_ change the list, I'm not sure whether that would do what you wanted. For example, if you start with `[1, 1, 1]`, and then change the first `1` to `1 + e.count(1) + 1`, it would become `5`. Then when you get to the second `1`, there are no longer three `1`s, but only `2`, so it would become `4`. Is `[5, 4, 3]` really the output you want there, rather than `[5, 5, 5]`?

Comment: Anyway, this is almost certainly a dup, but there are two different things it could be a dup of, depending on whether you want `[5, 4, 3]` or `[5, 5, 5]`, so please edit the question to explain which you want (or, if neither of those, explain what you do want, and why).

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a different list to store the values instead of iterating over the variable i.

```
newList = list() 
e=sorted(e)
for i in e:
    p=e.count(i)
    temp = (i + p + 1)
    newList.append(temp)
```